# how to load an image in opengl

Tags: image, opengl, load

I need to upload an image into my background...
Does anyone know how to do this?
I know I have to do the following steps:

```
1) Load image data into system memory
2) Generate a texture name with glGenTextures
3) Bind the texture name with gBindTexture
4) Set wrapping and filtering mode with glTexParameter
5) call glTexImage2D with the right parameters depending on the image nature to load image data into video memory
```

but I don't know how to put them in opengl

Comment: 4) is wromg. Setting texture filtering and wrapping mode are not required for loading an image. But you should (well better must) set the storage parameters before uploading with [glPixelStore](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glPixelStore.xml)

Comment: @datenwolf: Actually, not setting the filtering mode properly can lead to a texture that is incomplete.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Yes, but the OpenGL spec specifies that the minification filter can be set and changed anytime. So while it should be set at some point, it's not a requirement to set it before uploading the texture data. Also recall the way sampler objects work.

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL supports textures and images... but the user needs to provide the data. So you have to use sme library or additional code to load the data.

I suggest using very simple lib SOIL - http://www.lonesock.net/soil.html
Or some library provided by your SDK

in general:

```
load texture bytes into pBytes;
glTexImage2D(..., ..., ..., pBytes);
```